# How clone a group of fields in Meta Box Plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I use Meta Box Plugin. I have three custom meta fields in Pages. Name, Position, Photo(to upload).

I need to have ability to clone this group of sets multiple time. I found somewhere(there there another fields than mine), but it doesn't help.

```
'fields'=> array(
    array(
        'name'  => 'Country Releases',
        'id'    => "{$prefix}release",
        'type'  => 'group',
        'child_fields' => array(
            // These are just fields as would normally be listed in the 'fields' array.
            array(
                'name'    => 'Release Country:',
                'id'      => "{$prefix}release_country",
                'type'    => 'select',
                'options' => array(
                    'value1' => "USA",
                    'value2' => "Canada",
                ),
                'std' => "Select Country",
            ),
            array(
                'name' => "Release Year:",
                'id'   => "{$prefix}release_year",
                'type' => 'date',
                'js_options' => array(
                    'appendText'      => '(yyyy)',
                    'dateFormat'      => 'yy',
                ),
            ),
                ),
        'clone' => true,
    ),
)
```

Comment: What is "Meta Box plugin"? If it doesn't offer **repeatable fields** by default, you're out to writing *lots of code*..

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/

Comment: Why don't you try **Meta Box Group** extension? (https://metabox.io/plugins/meta-box-group/), it seems this is a paid feature though. Or you could change your plugin to CMB2, another great Custom Fields plugin for WordPress which supports repeatable fields within a Group, it lacks the drag and drop reorder feature but there are dozens of nice 3rd party add ons and CMB2 offers support for a satisfactory amount of field types. Google for it and compare its features with Meta Box Plugin, I believe it is really worth it to give it a try.